# Sizeof string literal

Tags: c++, string, sizeof

The following code

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* const foo = "f";
    const char bar[] = "b";
    cout << "sizeof(string literal) = " << sizeof( "f" ) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(const char* const) = " << sizeof( foo ) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(const char[]) = " << sizeof( bar ) << endl;
}
```

outputs

```
sizeof(string literal) = 2
sizeof(const char* const) = 4
sizeof(const char[]) = 2
```

on a 32bit OS, compiled with GCC.

1. Why does `sizeof` calculate the length of (the space needed for) the string literal ?
2. Does the string literal have a different type (from char* or char[]) when given to `sizeof` ?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

1. `sizeof("f")` must return 2, one for the 'f' and one for the terminating '\0'.
2. `sizeof(foo)` returns 4 on a 32-bit machine and 8 on a 64-bit machine because foo is a pointer.
3. `sizeof(bar)` returns 2 because bar is an array of two characters, the 'b' and the terminating '\0'.

The string literal has the type 'array of size N of `const char`' where N includes the terminal null.

Remember, arrays do not decay to pointers when passed to `sizeof`.

Comment: +1, but the type is actually 'array of N const characters' (const is not optional)

Comment: @dribeas: yes; I was ignoring the qualifiers, but you are pedantically correct.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ... the best kind of correct, especially when it comes to programming

Comment: the fact that the comment about `const` appeared minutes after the answer puts a smile on my face.

Comment: For 2., if memory serves, it's **NOT** guaranteed to be 4 or 8, according to the C standard. However the _spirit_ is correct - it will be the `sizeof(const char *)`, whatever that **pointer size** may be, and of course has no bearing on the actual length of the string. On some platforms/architectures/in some compilers (historically), pointer sizes and layouts changed depending on the type. This is why, for example, you must _explicitly_ cast pointers to their expected types (if they differed) in variadic function calls since the cast could change the pointer value entirely.

Comment: @AlexMarshall, I heard technically correct was the best kind of correct.  But I think you're technically correct in this case.  I'll update my _a posterioris._

Answer (score 14):

`sizeof` returns the size in bytes of its operand. That should answer question number 1. ;) Also, a string literal is of type "array to n const char" when passed to `sizeof`.

Your test cases, one by one:

- `"f"` is a string literal consisting of
  two characters, the character `f` and the terminating
  NUL.
- `foo` is a pointer (edit: regardless of qualifiers), and pointers seem to be 4 bytes long on your system..
- For `bar` the case is the same as `"f"`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why is a `char[]` the same as a striong literal though? I'm not a C/C++ expert, but I thought that `char[]` and `char*` were interchangable?

Comment: +1 on the general answer (and for speed :) A couple of precisions: foo IS a pointer (essentially qualifier does not apply) and in C++ the type is always "array of n const char" (constant-ness is not optional)

Comment: @dribeas: right you are, const always applies. @Matthew: char* and char[] are only the same under certain circumstances, the sizeof operator is not one of them.

Comment: @Matthew: Nope, arrays and pointers are *not* interchangeable. An array can be passed whenever a pointer is expected, as it *decays* to a pointer. But as long as the type is an array, it is *not* the same as a pointer.