# Difference between "3" and '3' in C

Tags: c

I tried to run the following program in C and got some output. Can you help me out why???

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char x='A';
  printf("%d%d%d",sizeof("3"),sizeof('3'),sizeof(3));
  return 0;
}
```

The output received is 2 4 4 using gcc in ubuntu 11.04 32 bit.

Similarly in other program:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char x='A';
  printf("%d%d",sizeof('A'),sizeof(x));
  return 0;
}
```

The output received is 4 1 using GCC in ubuntu 11.04 32 bit.

Can you help me out why the output is this way???

Comment: The tags are misleading, as this doesn't apply to C++.  In C, a char literal is an `int`.  In C++, it's a `char`.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392200/sizeof-string-literal

Comment: Note that when the argument to `sizeof` is not a type (as in all your examples), the parentheses are redundant: `sizeof 3`, `sizeof "3"`, ... are all ok. The parenthesis are redundant here too: `x = ((4) * (10)) + (2);`

Comment: @pmg: and they're redundant here, `(4 + (2 * 6) + 8) >> 2`. But personally I don't like the look of `4 + 2 * 6 + 8 >> 2`, and I often put redundant parens in C code. Not that it makes any difference in this case, but `sizeof` has very high precedence, so by habit I always use parens with it.

Answer (score 16):

In C, `char` literals are of integer type, so `sizeof('3') == sizeof(int)`. See this [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html) for details.

This is one of the areas where C and C++ differ (in C++ `sizeof('3')` is `1`).

Actually, correcting my previous assertion, `sizeof("3")` will yield 2 because "3" is treated as a 2-element character array.

> 6.3.2.1/3
>
> **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator** or the unary
>   & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Comment: `sizeof("3")` is performing a string-literal sizeof, which is 2 because it's the length of the literal (plus `\0`).

Comment: @AtoMerZ: because the C standard says so. AFAIK this is for historical reasons, and because nobody ever wanted to make a breaking change.

Comment: @cnicutar: of course. 6.3.2.1/3 of C99, 'except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator... an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to *type*"'.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Absolutely awesome!

Comment: @Steve - thanks, I was going through the standard to find the line: The part right before yours is: "Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or <b>is a string literal used to initialize an array</b>, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’", to clarify why `sizeof("literal")` doesn't return size of the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

In C

`3`: integer literal, type `int`
`'3'`: char literal, type `int`
`"3"`: string literal: type `char[2]`

In your second example, `x` denotes an object of type `char`.

Comment: `char[2]` is one of those annoying gotcha's for people new at the language.

Answer (score 2):

The '3' is converted to type int, which is 4 bytes.  However "3" is a string with two bytes.  The first byte is the char 3 and the second is the null terminator that gets appended to all strings.

Comment: There is no conversion. `'3'` is an `int` to start with.

Answer (score 1):

"C" is

```
char mystring[2];
mystring[0] = 'C';
mystring[1] = '\0';
```

While 'C' is

```
int mychar;
mychar = 'C';
```

Comment: This is true in C++, but not in C.  In C, it's `int mychar; mychar = 'C';`.

Answer (score 0):

`'3'` is a character constant.  In C, character constants have type `int` (in C++, they have type `char`).  Thus, `sizeof '3'` == `sizeof (int)`.

`"3"` is a string literal.  It is a 2-element array of `char` (`const char` in C++) with the values `{'3', '\0'}`.  `sizeof (char)` == 1 by definition, thus, `sizeof "3"` == 2.

`3` is an integer constant.  It has type `int`.  Thus, `sizeof 3` == `sizeof (int)`.

The variable `x` is declared as `char`, thus `sizeof x` == 1.