# How do i determine the length of a string if it's declared as const char *str?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have the following function structure

```
int function(const char *str)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I never could fully understand why people use `char *str` rather than simply `string str`. So I am guessing this basically means that the argument is the pointer to the first character of the string. How do I determine the length of the string `str` given that argument?

What I've tried is to iterate through `str`, if I hit a `NULL` or `""` or `''`, then that will be the end of it. However, none of these types are compatible for comparison. Please give me some clue regarding this. Thx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [get string size in bytes in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000544/get-string-size-in-bytes-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jamesdlin's answer is good, but to answer your question about comparisons, you would use `'\0'`, IE:

```
char* a = "a";
int size = 0;
while (a[size] != '\0')
    size++;
```

`NULL` is a pointer macro, `""` is an empty character array (Though it has an implicit `'\0'`, so you could theoretically do `strcmp(a, "");`), and `''` is just an empty character, I'm not sure that it's even a valid statement.

Also, `std::string` is a C++ class and does not exist in the C standard library.

Answer (score 3):

In C, strings are typically NUL-terminated.  For NUL-terminated strings, you can simply call `strlen(str)`.

> I never could fully understand why people use char *str rather than simply string str.

There is no `string` type in C.  You could add a `typedef`:

```
typedef char* string;
```

But adding `typedef`s for pointer types is generally a bad idea (because now you need a separate `typedef` for `const char*`; `const string` would *not* be the same thing).

And while doing so might seem like a good idea, in practice it will obscure your code since `char*`/`const char*` for strings is the norm.

Comment: Note: Strings, by the C spec definition, are _always_ `'\0'` terminated.  An array of `char` without a terminating null character is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, `char *str` is a pointer to the first character of a char array, but C has no predefined string type - it's just a zero-terminated `char` array. Instead of trying to write a function (although it would be a good student exercise), just call the library function in `<string.h>` with `strlen (str);` which takes a pointer to the character array. You don't pass `*str` or `&str` but just `str` if it is a declared array variable. If memory was allocated dynamically, you pass the allocated pointer, so if the pointer was declared as `char *memstr` you pass it as `memstr`. As others have said, it's best not to try to define a string, better to understand how the char array works.