# Please explain the output of sizeof()

Tags: c, sizeof

I am new in c programming, and I am trying to understand the `sizeof` function.

Please help me understand how this program works:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main( )
{
    printf ( "\n%d %d %d", sizeof ( '3'), sizeof ( "3" ), sizeof ( 3 ) ) ;
}
```

I am getting output as `4 2 4`.

However, I am not able to understand the reason I get this output.
Kindly explain it.

Comment: You just answered your own title

Comment: `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `sizeof ( '3')`, it is the size of **character constant** which is `int` so you are getting value as `4` on your machine.
2. `sizeof ( "3" )`, it is size of string i.e. `2`. 
   String `"3"` is made of 2 character `('3'+'\0')` = `"3"`. And we know`sizeof(char)` is 1.
3. `sizeof ( 3 )`, it is size of `int` which is `4` on your machine.

Answer (score 9):

First off, a couple of notes:

- You should not omit the return type of main. See [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)
- Enable warnings. On GCC, you would generally use `-Wall`. This should give you a warning about your format string.
- In C99, you should use `%zu` instead of `%d` as explained in [How to print size_t variable portably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524611/how-to-print-size-t-variable-portably). The C standard says the type of the result of `sizeof` is `size_t` (§6.5.3.4/5). It is [undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) if your conversion specifiers don't match your arguments.

Onto your question.

- In the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com), [question
  8.9](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html) explains that character constants in C are of type `int`, so `sizeof('3')` is
  `sizeof(int)` (which appears to be 4 on your machine.)
- When applied to arrays, `sizeof` returns the size of the array in
  bytes. For example, `sizeof(int[10])` returns 40 on a machine where
  `sizeof(int)` is 4. Since `sizeof(char)` is 1, it will equal the
  amount of characters in a string literal. As explained by [Jonathan
  Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1392228/3920237):

  > 1. sizeof("f") must return 2, one for the 'f' and one for the terminating '\0'.
  > 2. [...]
  >
  > The string literal has the type 'array of size N of char' where N
  >   includes the terminal null.
  >
  > Remember, [arrays do not decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer)<sup>1</sup>
  >   to pointers when passed to sizeof.

  <sub>1 [Exception to array not decaying into a
  pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer)</sub>
- And lastly, `sizeof(3)` is `sizeof(int)`.