# What does the "^@" mean in file?

Tags: c, gcc, ascii, control-characters

Code:

```
int fd;
fd = open("fruit", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "apple", sizeof("apple"));
close(fd);
```

I compile it with

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
```

and run as

```
$ ./test
```

Then I open the `fruit` file, and I see the following in the file:

```
apple^@
```

What does the `^@` mean?

Comment: Change `sizeof("apple")` to `strlen("apple")` to get rid of it

Comment: In these cases, use a hexdump program to be sure about the content of the file http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/06/3-different-ways-of-dumping-hex.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is the null character code `'\0'`. Certain editors like [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) display it as `^@`.

`sizeof("apple")` would return 6 because it includes the null character used to terminate strings.

Answer (score 39):

The `^@` is the way an ASCII NUL is commonly represented in printable form. That is the same as the `@` character with some bits removed:

```
@ = 0100
^@ = 0
```

and it is the same as `'\0'` (the string terminator in C).  Because it is the string terminator, you would not see it from `printf` or its related functions, but you can readily create it using the block-oriented `write`.  For example, you could have written

```
write(fd,"apple\0orange",sizeof("apple\0orange"));
```

and seen

```
apple^@orange^@
```

because *every* double-quoted literal in C has a trailing string terminator which is counted in its size.  If you had meant to write the string without its terminator, you could have done this:

```
const char *s = "apple";
write(fd,s,strlen(s));
```

thereby eliminating two problems in the example: (a) incorrect length and (b) possibly using inconsistent string content and length by ensuring both are the same item.  See *[Sizeof string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392200/sizeof-string-literal)* for some comments on (a).

`NUL` is one of the 32 ASCII control characters whose values range from 0 to 31, called *C0 controls*.
All of these ASCII control characters are typically shown in this way (for a printable form), using the character corresponding to adding 64 (0100) to the control character's value.

ASCII `DEL` is 127 (0177).  Displaying it as `^?` is a special case which is more recent than the other ASCII control characters. For instance, X/Open terminfo (curses) does not define a printable form for this character, although it does for the others.  Unlike the other ASCII control characters, `DEL` is formed by OR'ing all (seven) bits into the character.

ASCII is a 7-bit code, of course.  Many other codes were developed; ASCII corresponds to the [POSIX portable character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap06.html), so it is frequently encountered.

It is easy to find tables of ASCII characters with a web search. Most of these tables (or their accompanying discussion) veer off into misinformation.  Here is a link to a reasonably factual page, entitled [*ASCII Character Set*](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html).  It states

> The Control key *subtracts* 64 from the value of the keys that it modifies.

However, the statement is only correct if the key is one of those from the set `@`, `A`, `B`, etc.  If you apply that to other keys, the results are perhaps interesting but not useful.  Rather, in a C program you would do a logical masking, e.g.,

```
ch = ch & 037;
```

to obtain a character in the range 0 to 31.

Comment: DEL too, which can be shown as `^?` (in this case with the 0x40 bit cleared rather than set).

Comment: Consider adding "because there is no *defined* printable form" to the 4th paragraph :)

Comment: BTW—Unicode does [define](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) symbol characters for control characters: ␀ ␡ (Your browser might not display them, though.)

Comment: My browser shows those in your comment, but they are in small caps, and only readable because I know what you intended.