# three indirection pointer how to change indirected string's index character -- three indirection pointer I am getting as function parameter

Tags: c

I have a function like this `void tm(char ***path)` can u please tell how to change second character of string that I am getting in `tm(char ***path)` function from some other function

```
int handle_process(struct connection *con_obj,char **path,char **request_type)
{
    tm(&path)
}

void tm(char ***path)
{
    
    **(*path+1)='x';
}
```

and print the updated path string in `handle_process` function. I am getting segFault

Comment: You must provide a [mre]. If we do not know what parameter you have passed, we cannot guess what is the cause of the SEGFAULT.

Comment: There is no reason in the world to hide a string behind three stars pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. For example you dynamically allocated an array of pointers and then you decided to reallocate the array in other function.:)

Comment: `char ***path` isn't a string, it might be a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a string though. Is it?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'd vote for a federal law against such a code.

Comment: If you just want to change a letter in the string, why not pass a `char *` to `tm`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp In this case the programming would be too simple and everybody would think that he is a programmer.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `@EugeneSh. For example you dynamically allocated an array of pointers and then you decided to reallocate the array in other function.:)` exactly I am dynamically allocating `char **path` like this `*path =malloc(sizeof(char)*j+1);` in `handle_process()` function can u show me now please?

Comment: You are going to join the elite :) https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer  . When you succeed you can go even further : 4 starts 5 stars and even 7 starts

Comment: @JohnnyMopp `If you just want to change a letter in the string, why not pass a char * to tm` if I am getting updated value in `handle_process` function inside handle_process function that that will be fine. given that I do not want to change the signature of `handle_process` function. expecially parameters. must be same

Comment: @0___________ I did not say I will use it but I should know which I do think there is no problem with knowing. u probably know this too

Comment: It is still not clear why you need to pass a `char ***` to `tm`. If `*path` is a `char *`, why can't you pass that to `tm`? See the first comment about creating a [mcve]. Anyway, if you really want a `char ***` you can do `(**path)[1] = 'x';`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp actually I need to change what ever string hidden in `***path` to get changed in tm() function then I want to printf the updated value of **path containing string in `handle_process` function. in `handle_process` function I only want to call `tm` function which should update path indirected pointer contained string in `handle_process` function. I think I did my best to explain this. I really don't know what I am missing in my explanation. so is it clear now

Comment: When you say "change" the string do you mean reallocate the pointer or modify the strings contents? I don't know why you won't create a [mcve]. Even if it is contrived, it will help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user786: You would only need to pass a pointer to `path` if you were trying to update the value of `path` itself.  You're not doing that - you're trying to update the thing `path` *points to*.  So there's no need to introduce an extra level of indirection here.  Just pass `path` to `tm` as `tm( path );` and declare the function to take a `char **` - `void tm( char **path )`.  Then in the body of the code you'd just need to do `(*path)[1] = 'x';` (the parentheses are necessary because you don't want to index into `path`, you want to index into what it *points to*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to understand if you split it into more than one operation (to be more difficult second character of the second string):

```
void tm(char ***path)
{
    char **twoStars = *path;
    char *singleStar = twoStars[1];
    singleStar[1] = 'x';
}

void tm1(char ***path)
{
    (*((*path) + 1))[1] = 'z';
}

//or only pointer arithmetic
void tm2(char ***path)
{
    *(*((*path) + 1)+1) = '0';
}

//or only indexes 
void tm3(char ***path)
{
    path[0][1][1] = 'z';
}



int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "hello";
    char str2[] = "world";

    char **strings =  (char *[]){str1, str2};

    printf("string1 = `%s`, string2 = `%s`\n", strings[0], strings[1]);
    tm(&strings);
    printf("string1 = `%s`, string2 = `%s`\n", strings[0], strings[1]);
    tm1(&strings);
    printf("string1 = `%s`, string2 = `%s`\n", strings[0], strings[1]);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o1aqvT913

and the result:

```
string1 = `hello`, string2 = `world`
string1 = `hello`, string2 = `wxrld`
string1 = `hello`, string2 = `wzrld`
```

EDIT (OP comments):

example of the "chained" calls to functions increasing level of indirection

```
void tm(char ***path)
{
    *(*((*path) + 0)+1) = '0';
}
void bar(char **ptr)
{
    tm(&ptr);
}

void foo(char *str)
{
    bar(&str);
}


int main(void)
{
    char str1[] = "hello";

    foo(str1);
    printf("string1 = `%s`\n", str1);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/oxGYonsxz

Comment: so u are assigning top level container pointer which is `*path` like `char **twoStars = *path;` and so if I do `char *singleStar = *twoStars;` this I will get me string closest container pointer `char *singleStar` which is char pointer pointing to actual string charaters. am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes. But you need to have correct referenced object at any level of indirection

Comment: are u sure because its not changing earlier functions in call stack like `process()-->handle_process()-->tm` why value is not changing in `process` function I am calling `handle_process` function like `handle_process(con_obj,&path,&request_type);` in `process()` function and passing address of `char *path` as in `handle_process(con_obj,&path,&request_type);`

Comment: in `process()` function in which I am doing `char *path=NULL` before calling `handle_process()` function and passing address of `*path=NULL` in a function call to `process_handle` like process_handle(..,&path) function I am allocating space for char *path =NULL  in `process_handle` function

Comment: @user786 I barely understand what you mean bu see the second example.